# Germany TK insurance in Italy

Tags: germany, italy, insurance, long-stay-visas

I am traveling to Germany with national visa (D) . I have TK insurance in Germany. I may also visit Italy (few weeks) for business meetings. While I am in Italy my TK insurance covers the Italy ? or do I need to take another insurance ?
(I do not have German resident permit yet as it is in process and it will take around 2 months to get)

Comment: What is TK insurance?

Comment: Its state  Health Insurance company  in Germany.    https://www.tk.de/techniker

Answer (score 2):

Your TK Gesundheitskarte is an [EHIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Health_Insurance_Card). You don't need any additional health coverage while travelling within the EEA/Switzerland.